# Ignore empty xml tags

Tags: xml

I am comparing two XML files and want to ignore empty XML elements since they may be slightly different in the two files but the difference is not important to my application.  For example:

```
<XXX></XXX>
<XXX />
```

What would the grammar be to tell beyond compare to ignore if one file has an empty tag as one of the above and the other file has the other.  It would also be great if I could also ignore it if there is a empty tag in one file and nothing in the other file.

Comment: Sorry the above was stripped of the example when I posted.  It should have included "<XXX> </XXX>" and "<XXX />"

Comment: Welcome to SO, use the code block format to preserve code and tags.

Comment: BTW how would I have included the above xml tags in the question?  I tried escaping but that did not work.

Comment: Did you try using the Code button on the editor toolbar?  You can also manually indent the code.  For inline you can also use back-ticks ` (under the tilde / ~ on US keyboards).

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0, `deep-equal(doc('doc1.xml'), doc('doc2.xml'))` will return true for these two examples. In fact it will deal with many of the trivial variations between XML documents, such as the order of attributes and the choice of attribute delimiters. You definitely want to be comparing parsed XML rather than raw lexical XML.

Having said that, the `deep-equal()` function isn't perfect, and nor is any other comparator, because everyone's requirements are different (for example, do comments matter?). Saxon includes a parameterized version of `deep-equal()` which can help you refine your comparisons. But even that isn't always enough: for example some people want comparisons in which the order of elements is ignored.